# Read subdirectory names and split into subdirectories based on dir name

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, grep

This is probably really simple but I'm ox-hilling it for the better part of the day.

**Problem:**
I have several folders coming out of an app that I need to get into sub-folders. I'm going with separators as I'm currently doing it by hand and it's a good visual indicator where things go.

**Example:**
Dir Name: `category---subcat---page`

**Desired Result:**

- category/

  - /subcat/

    - /page/

The final directory in the hierarchy is the one where the respective folder contents go. So if it's just one `---` separator, it only goes one directory deep. If it's `---...---` it goes two deep and so on.

*EDIT*

My feeble attempt so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS='---'
line="category---subcat---page"

dir=($line)

mkdir ${dir[0]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: My original answer did not apply, so I'm rewriting it to suggest a somewhat different answer.*

Bash can perform string substitution when expanding the value of a variable.  Let's use that:

```
line='category---subcat---page'
mkdir -p "${line//---//}"
```

The expression `//---//` finds each instance of the string `---` and replaces it with the string `/` as the `$line` variable is expanded. (the expression `/---//` will only replace the first instance)

This gives `mkdir -p` the directory path string `category/subcat/page`, which will be created as the directory tree:

```
category/
         subcat/
                page/
```

Comment: You can't have slashes in folder names. Hence the separator. The reason behind my question is to have like 20+ folders that all need to be moved to sub-folders based on their filename because the tool itself doesn't support exporting to sub-folders. 

Maybe running a find and replace through the string for each could work. Then mkdir them and move the contents over at the last step. Hmm, need to try in the morning. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't see your edit before I ventured with a string replacement approach as well. Yours is so much more elegant than mine though. the `//---//` part is genius. I had no idea you could do string replacement this way. Just need to figure out how to get the last instance and I'm done. 

Comment: @Voodoopants thank you.  I've spent a lot of time looking through the section of the bash man page where parameter expansions are described, trying to find ways to manipulate strings without forking external awk/sed/grep processes.  Some of the expansions are very useful.  However, it's a balance between getting a script done quickly vs. groveling through man pages and writing little experimental script snippets to figure out a new technique.  With the latter, I learn and it pays off in the long run, but many times it's better to get the task done with the quick-n-dirty method.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it. With your help I got a pretty good and clean solution now. Using `cp` to get the input path's contents to the new string (with your expression in it) gave me an automatic backup as opposed to my previous attempts with `mv`.